# Why is my website taking so long to load?

Tags: html, performance, http

When I check the web console to understand the sections that are making my webpage slow it tells me the following are making my webpage take 40 seconds:

[image]

The domain tells me it is *blocked* for 20 seconds and is then taking another 20 seconds to *connect*. I am running this within a private window

EDIT:

Here is my head tag, however everything else within the head tag on the web console is taking a reasonably small time to load which is why I think it may be something else:

```
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description"
      content="{% block meta_description %}{% endblock %}">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/vendor/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/main.css') }}">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/vendor/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker.4.13.30.min.css') }}">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-lZFHibXzMHo3GGeehn1hudTAP3Sc0uKXBXAzHX1sjtk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

{% if config['ANALYTICS_GOOGLE_UA'] %}
  <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', "{{ config['ANALYTICS_GOOGLE_UA'] }}", 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  </script>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information, such as a screenshot of the whole screen, and relevant code, particularly of the code that triggers the XHR, as text (not an image)?

Comment: @polymath we need more infos about the meta head scripts between <head></head> or any .js files included , remove the cache or open the page on Incognito and capture the requests again

Comment: Please try to [create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At the very least, a complete & verifiable example.

Comment: @K3rnel31 I've added my html head tag upon your request and ran the request in incognito. The scripts within my head tag are loading in 100 to 600ms which is why I haven't added them and believe the source of the issue may be something else.

Comment: @SolomonUcko I believe the xhr may be because I was originally loading the page in gmail. There was no request for it once I switched to incognito but it still takes 40s to load.

Comment: @polymath wich server are you using ? iis or apache or what? and where are the files hosted ? on your localmachine or on offshore service ? it looks like firewall or something slowing the service

Comment: @K3rnel31 I am using an nginx server in a docker container hosted on digital ocean with an iptables firewall. I will add the logs from my docker-compose in an edit

Comment: @polymath yeah i knew it , remove your iptables , and try it ;) good luck , you need to add a hardware iptables like mikrotic wich has 2 cores

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried hitting that problematic URL directly with a browser and see how long it takes?  It could be the server that is serving that URL is very slow or some firewall/gateway on the network you are testing on.